Swap tokens on Uniswap v3 with Python code. Error - Function invocation failed due to no matching argument types
Code to swap one token for another:
from web3 import Account, Web3
from abi import UNISWAP_V3_ROUTER2_ABI, WETH9_ABI, MIN_ERC20_ABI
import eth_abi.packed

private_key = "pppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppp"

chain_id = 42161
rpc_endpoint = "https://arb1.arbitrum.io/rpc"

web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(rpc_endpoint))
account = Account.from_key(private_key)

total_gas_used_buy = 0
amount_in = 0.00000004

weth_address = web3.to_checksum_address("0x35751007a407ca6feffe80b3cb397736d2cf4dbe")
usdc_address = web3.to_checksum_address("0xaf88d065e77c8cc2239327c5edb3a432268e5831")
swap_router02_address = web3.to_checksum_address("0x68b3465833fb72A70ecDF485E0e4C7bD8665Fc45")

# load contracts
swap_router_contract = web3.eth.contract(address=swap_router02_address, abi=UNISWAP_V3_ROUTER2_ABI)
weth_contract = web3.eth.contract(address=weth_address, abi=WETH9_ABI)
usdc_contract = web3.eth.contract(address=usdc_address, abi=MIN_ERC20_ABI)

# swap
path = eth_abi.packed.encode_packed(['address','uint24','address'], [weth_address,500,usdc_address])

tx_params = (
    path,
    account.address,
    amount_in, # amount in
    0 #min amount out
)

swap_buy_tx = swap_router_contract.functions.exactInput(tx_params).build_transaction(
        {
            'from': account.address,
            'gas': 500000,
            "maxPriorityFeePerGas": web3.eth.max_priority_fee,
            "maxFeePerGas": 15000000,
            'nonce': web3.eth.get_transaction_count(account.address),
        })

Error:
web3.exceptions.Web3ValidationError:
Could not identify the intended function with name \`exactInput\`, positional arguments with type(s) \`(bytes,address,float,int)\` and keyword arguments with type(s) \`{}\`.

Found 1 function(s) with the name \`exactInput\`: \['exactInput((bytes,address,uint256,uint256))'\]

Function invocation failed due to no matching argument types.

I tried changing the type of variables by substituting int()

The problem solved. 'amount_in = 0.00000004' must be uint256
